# Call a Component method in Directive Angular 2

Tags: angular2-directives

I have a directive which is supposed to call a method from component, but it fails doing this, what should be wrong ?

Here I will put the `Directive`, and a fragment of `Component` for understanding the problem..

> Directive

```
import { Directive, EventEmitter, HostListener, Input, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';

import { GridComponent } from '../components/grid/grid.component';

import { Cell } from '../cell';
import { KEY_CODE } from '../keyCode.enum';

@Directive({
    selector: '[appControl]',
})

export class GridDirective {

    constructor(public gridComponent: GridComponent) {}

    @HostListener('window:keydown', ['$event'])
    handleKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent) {
        console.log(event.key);
        const ITEMS = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Grid'));
        let key;
        switch (event.key) {
            case 'ArrowLeft': key = KEY_CODE.LEFT_ARROW;
                break;
            case 'ArrowUp': key = KEY_CODE.UP_ARROW;
                break;
            case 'ArrowRight': key = KEY_CODE.RIGHT_ARROW;
                break;
            case 'ArrowDown': key = KEY_CODE.DOWN_ARROW;
                break;
        }
        this.gridComponent.move(ITEMS, key);
    }
}
```

> And here's the component method which it is supposed to call

```
move(array: Cell[][], key: KEY_CODE) {
    localStorage.setItem('lastMove', JSON.stringify(key));
    const DATA = this.gridService.move(array, this.score, key);
    array = DATA.dataSheet;
    this.score = DATA.rating;
    this.best = this.gridService.scoreSender(this.score, this.best);
    localStorage.setItem('Grid', JSON.stringify(array));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's a wrong way to use a component as a service,
you should pass the "this" value from html and then assign it to gridComponent variable and for passing parameter to directive you can use input decorator

```
gridComponent :GridComponent;
@Input('appControl') set setGridComponent(gridComponent) {
   this.gridComponent = gridComponent;
}

/// in html use property binding to pass the value to it

[appControl]="this"
```

Comment: where should i put the `@Input`, in `gridComponent`?

Comment: I have a problem with binding, I do the binding in the first `<div>` of the component's template and there appears an error saying that it can't bind 'appControl' since it's an unknown property of 'div'.

Comment: did you import directive in app.module like that
    @NgModule({
       declaration:[GridDirective]
    })

Comment: Yes, it is imported, and added to declarations and exports in `@NgModule`

Comment: I edited my solution please check it and sorry for mistake!

Comment: "it's a wrong way to use a component as a service", I don't agree, it isn't as a service, its just injecting it into my directive. and its good practice. angular also used to do this in their repository.

Comment: sorry for the wrong description btw it's a wrong way to make a component injectable, what is the point of SGA if you did it? how you can reuse this component